# Unable to find Printer Driver RICOH MP 2001L in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, ricoh

**OS :** Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Unable to find Printer Driver RICOH MP 2001L in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Can anybody tell me any alternative way to install the same ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this printer machine works only upto windows 7 & former OS.

Also it is not compatible for Linux OS as said in its manual.